# SQL Server create trigger for all user tables

Tags: stored-procedures, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a trigger that needs to be created for each and every user table in a database. The trigger starts with the following:

```
DECLARE @TableName varchar(100)
SET @TableName = 'mytable'
```

The commands proceed based on the table name.

Is there a way to automate the process of creating the trigger?

For example looping through the user tables and set the local variable accordingly before create the trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT 'CREATE TRIGGER ' + QUOTENAME('tblTrace' + name) + '
ON ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS

**your trigger code goes here**

GO'
FROM dbo.sysobjects 
WHERE xtype = 'U'
```